# Concrete balanced category

Tags: category-theory

A category is called *balanced* if every bimorphism is an isomorphism.

Consider a concrete category such that every bijective morphism is a isomorphism. Does the category is balanced? Does converse is true?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513847/balanced-categories-and-conservative-functors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the category of rings, every bijective morphism is an isomorphism, but the inclusion of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is a bimorphism that is not an isomorphism, so the category of rings is not balanced.

Comment: The converse is true, of course: a bijective morphism in a concrete category must be a bimorphism and hence if a concrete is balanced, all its bijective morphisms are isomorphisms.

Comment: Is there a general name for concrete categories where isomorphisms are exactly bijective morphisms?

Comment: See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conservative+functor

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, whenever you see a definition that says: A thing X is called Y if.....

what they really mean is: A thing X is called Y iff...

In other words the definition is a logical equivalence (a logical biconditional).

The definition of [balanced category](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/balanced+category) in ncatlab  is an exanple of this usage

Comment: Would the downvoter mind to explain his/her downvote? The OP wrote: if every bimorphism is an iso we have a balanced category, if we have a balanced category , is it true that every bimorphism is an iso? I simply said : yes it is true. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I wasn't the down-voter, but you should have another look at the original question to see why you were down-voted. "Bimorphism" and "bijective morphism" are distinct notions, so the question has some mathematical content.