# Balanced categories and conservative functors.

Tags: category-theory

If $\mathbf{C}$ is a balanced category, then every faithful functor out of $\mathbf{C}$ is conservative.

*Proof.* Suppose $\mathbf{C}$ is a balanced category and let $F$ denote a faithful functor out of $\mathbf{C}.$ Suppose $\varphi$ is an arrow of $\mathbf{C}$ such that $F(\varphi)$ is an isomorphism. Then $F(\varphi)$ is both monic and epic. By faithfulness, this means that $\varphi$ is both monic and epic. By balancedness, this means that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. Hence $F$ is conservative.

> **Question.** Does the converse hold?
>
> I.e. if every faithful functor out of $\mathbf{C}$ is conservative, is $\mathbf{C}$ necessarily balanced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following Qiaochu's suggestion, we can obtain a result of the kind you are looking for.

Say a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ is a weak equivalence if it is both monic and epic. Then:

> The following are equivalent:
>
> - $\mathcal{C}$ is a balanced category.
> - Every faithful functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is conservative, and the weak equivalences in $\mathcal{C}$ satisfy the right Ore condition, i.e. for every morphism $f : X \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and every weak equivalence $y : Y' \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, there is a commutative square of the form below,
>     $$\require{AMScd}
>   \begin{CD}
>   X' @>{x}>> X \\
>   @V{f'}VV @VV{f}V \\
>   Y' @>>{y}> Y
>   \end{CD}$$
>     where $x : X' \to X$ is also a weak equivalence in $\mathcal{C}$.

The downward implication is straightforward, so assume the second set of hypotheses. Since weak equivalences in $\mathcal{C}$ are monomorphisms, the right Ore condition suffices to establish a calculus of right fractions. Concretely, that means we have the following construction of the localisation of $\mathcal{C}$ with respect to weak equivalences:

- The objects are as in $\mathcal{C}$.
- The morphisms $X \to Y$ are equivalence classes zigzags of the form below,
  $$\begin{CD}
  X @<<< \bullet @>>> Y
  \end{CD}$$
  where the leftward-pointing arrow is a weak equivalence in $\mathcal{C}$, and given any commutative diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ of the form below,
  $$\begin{CD}
  X @<<< \bullet @>>> Y \\
  @| @AAA @| \\
  X @<<< \bullet @>>> Y \\
  @| @VVV @| \\
  X @<<< \bullet @>>> Y
  \end{CD}$$
  where all the leftward-pointing arrows are weak equivalences in $\mathcal{C}$, we define the top row and bottom row to be equivalent zigzags.

Call this category $\mathcal{D}$. There is an evident functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ and it is faithful: indeed, given a commutative diagram of the form below,
$$\begin{CD}
X @= X @>>> Y \\
@| @AAA @| \\
X @<<< X' @>>> Y \\
@| @VVV @| \\
X @= X @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
where $X' \to X$ is an epimorphism, the two arrows $X \to Y$ must be equal.

Thus, under the hypothesis that every faithful functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is conservative, every weak equivalence in $\mathcal{C}$ is already an isomorphism, i.e. $\mathcal{C}$ is balanced.

It may be worth noting that there is a non-balanced category $\mathcal{C}$ for which the above right Ore condition is satisfied, namely $\mathbf{Top}$. But there is an obvious faithful non-conservative functor $\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$, so we haven't learned much.

Comment: If we take $X'$ to be the pullback, I guess it suffices for weak equivalences to be stable under pullback. Pullbacks of monos are monos, so we're done if pullbacks of epis are epis.

Comment: Indeed. This is precisely what happens for $\mathbf{Top}$.

Answer (score 4):

If this is true, the following seems to me like the only proof strategy that could work. Suppose $f : c \to d$ is monic and epic. Then you should try to show that the localization functor $C \to C[f^{-1}]$ is faithful (presumably using the fact that $f$ is both left and right cancellative). If that's true, then by hypothesis it's conservative, so since $f$ is an iso in this localization, it was already an iso in $C$.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to show this off the top of my head.